# Which order is better? "My best friend, Jody, is my cousin." vs "My cousin Jody is my best friend."

Tags: word-order, sentence-choice

1. My best friend, Jody, is my cousin.
2. My cousin Jody is my best friend.

Which one is better?

Comment: Are these sentences quoted from somewhere?  If not the answer to q1 is "Because you didn't type any!"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both are grammatically valid. Neither is "better" but they have slightly different meanings. (1) emphasizes that Jody is the speaker's best friend, and says that Jody is also the speaker's cousin. (2) emphasizes the relation of cousin more. So it depends what one wants to express which is better. It is also to some extent a matter of style.